# Replication server setup for mysql using phpmyadmin Cpanel

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, replication, cpanel, database-replication

I am hosting my website on a shared server, with a mysql database which I can access it using phpmyadmin only. Can we setup replication mechanism to replicate my DB to my local server periodically?

something like periodically it should dump the data from my live server to my local server or atleast create a dump file.

Thanks,

Comment: Later versions of phpmyadmin, such as 3.3.7, have a synchronise option. Which version are you on?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I am using CPanel version 11.28.87, please help me in synchronising my DB.

Comment: Do you want to try putting this in a browser: http://username:password@website:2082/getsqlbackup/website_database.gzwhere username and password are as they say, and 2082 is whatever port you use. On my later version of cpanel that gets you a zipped copy of your database backup file. You can then unzip it and run it locally to update your local database.

Comment: I've turned it into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this URL: `http://username:password@website:2082/getsqlbackup/website…database.gz` to get a gzipped copy of your databse. username and password are as they say, and 2082 is whatever port you use.

You can use `wget` in a batch file to get it automatically.